# Delay on web requests/inconsistent network speed on wifi

Tags: networking, wifi, internet

I think this is going to be a somewhat vague question, but bear with me, because I haven't had an idea how to solve this for months now. I'm getting desperate.

My boss keeps nagging me about slow wifi, and he is getting pretty pissed about it. His problem is that all of his network requests (browsing, online bank transactions, etc) are executed with a delay of a few seconds. A while ago he was also complaining about inconsistent network speed. We have looked at this 3 times, and completely setup the wifi network from scratch once. Wired connections and VOIP calls are working fine (we had problems with calls dropping before). I just benchmarked the network speed with some speed tests and everything seems in order. At my own desk I don't notice anything, because I'm using a wired connection. I tried working from my laptop (connected to the wifi) for a day, but I haven't noticed any slowdowns. My boss mainly uses an iPhone 7 and some Asus laptop, I can check specific model numbers etc if needed.

Our setup:

- a pfSense box (main routing, DNS, DHCP, Firewall, QoS, etc)
- a Draytek Vigor 2860 router/access point (only functions as wireless access point right now)
- a Netgear Nighthawk X6 (configured as access point)
- all connected on the same LAN with a few managed switches

Things we have tried:

- Disconnected extra access points. They were all operating on the same channel with the same SSID, and this caused me some trouble before. We now have two access points with the same SSID on different channels
- Switching from 2.4 GHz to 5 GHz. No noticeable difference.
- Checked the main DNS server configuration. Removed an old entry for a now inactive DNS server. No noticeable difference.
- Set up the wifi network from scratch, as I stated above. Boss says he still has 'slow wifi'
- Changing the channels on the 2.4Ghz band. No results

Any ideas what the problem could be? How can we troubleshoot this better?

Comment: Wifi is inherently unreliable. Troubleshooting wireless is very difficult, and quite expensive (spectrum analyzer a aren't cheap). Have you verified the boss's claims? What wireless hardware are you using?

Comment: We're trying to verify his claims, but so far we are unable to. But because he's getting pretty pissed by the fact it isn't fixed, I'm looking into it once again. He's using an iPhone 7. He has his laptop with him at the moment so I'm unable to check the network card. One access point is a Netgear Nighthawk X6, one is a Draytek Vigor2860. I'm starting to think the problem is in his head rather than in the hardware

Comment: When you scan for wireless networks in your area, how many networks do you see? Have you tried changing wifi channels?

Comment: There are a bunch. One of our networks is on its own channel the other shares a channel with one other network (not one of us). We have tried changing the 2.4GHz channels. No results.

Comment: That's likely the problem. Wifi is a shared spectrum, and performance degrades quickly when the RF spectrum is noisy. In general, sticking with 5GHz should improve performance. One key, and you should be doing this anyway, is to use quality APs (not consumer-grade equipment). I'm a big fan of Ruckus, but Meraki, Aerohive, Cisco, and others make quality gear as well.

Comment: I'll tell him to stick to the 5 Ghz network. We used to have some Cisco AP's, but they gave problems, so we disconnected them. Although our current AP's are consumer routers, they seem to do the job better. I will give him the option to upgrade to better AP's.

Comment: The key is something that has centralized management.